# Can I use isKeyInCache and put method replace putIfAbsent on ehcache?

Tags: java, ehcache

Can I use isKeyInCache and put method replace putIfAbsent on ehcache?

Here is my test code, performance varies widely

```
// putIfAbsent 
time = System.nanoTime();
ehcache.putIfAbsent(new Element(assetUid, asset));
estimated = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(estimated - time);

// isKeyInCache and put
time = System.nanoTime();
if (!ehcache.isKeyInCache(assetUid)) {
    ehcache.put(new Element(assetUid, asset));
}
estimated = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(estimated - time);
```

And console output

```
1693409
18235
```

Or you have other suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that putIfAbsent() will respect locks and race conditions (in other words synchronized somewhere) to ensure that  the entry is indeed put only if nothing is there...or currently being written by another thread etc...

The call isKeyInCache will not.
From http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html#isKeyInCache(java.lang.Object):
"An inexpensive check to see if the key exists in the cache.
This method is not synchronized. It is possible that an element may exist in the cache and be removed before the check gets to it, or vice versa. Since no assertions are made about the state of the Element it is possible that the Element is expired, but this method still returns true."

Which explains the timing difference...

From the above, it really depends on your use case...can you live with the statement: "It is possible that an element may exist in the cache and be removed before the check gets to it, or vice versa"? If yes, go with isKeyInCache() check...
If you want certainty during that check, stick with putIfAbsent()...